# How to redirect from view in sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, sinatra, link-to

I need to make a link in haml view that will redirect to another page on clik. In rails I could use helper link_to signup_url, 'Sign up!', but I don't know how to make it in sinatra. So, can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erb:

```
<a href="#{url '/signup'}">Sign up!</a>
```

Haml:

```
%a{ href: url('/signup') } Sign up!
```

Sinatra doesn't have link helpers like Rails does, but it does have a `url` method for dealing with mounting your app on different endpoints, [described here](http://www.sinatrarb.com/2011/03/03/sinatra-1.2.0.html#url-helper).

Also, what you describe is not a "redirect", it's just a link.

Comment: Thanks, seems like thing I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the link in your view point to a path that your Sinatra performs a redirect on?  Example:

HAML:

`%a{:href => "/redirect-link-path"} Sign up!`

Sinatra:

```
get '/redirect-link-path' do
  redirect to('/some-other-path')
end
```

Docs:  http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Browser%20Redirect

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Not exactly what I was looking for, but helpful as well!